# Trying to put button and using center mode

Tags: java, swing, awt

Im trying to make a option menu to be able to choose flags to be displayed, Im trying to put the tailand button on the left down corner and it seems it does not want to budge.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Flags {
public static void startup() {
    Dimension d = new Dimension(400,300);
    JFrame menu = new JFrame("Flag Menu");
    menu.setResizable(true);
    JButton tailand = new JButton("Tailand");
    JPanel tailandPanel = new JPanel();
    tailand.setLayout(null);
    tailandPanel.setLayout(null);


    tailand.setBounds(300,100,100,600);
    tailandPanel.add(tailand);
    menu.add(tailandPanel);
    tailandPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    tailand.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    tailandPanel.setPreferredSize(d);
    tailand.setPreferredSize(d);
    tailandPanel.setLocation(1, 1);
    tailand.setLocation(1, 1);
    menu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    menu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    menu.setSize(600, 400);
    menu.setResizable(false);
    menu.setVisible(true);
    menu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
}
```

I have tried `tailand.setPreferredSize(d);` and `tailandpanel.setPreferredSize(d);` but no luck.
Also Is their a way to use center mode? (Eg. Give 300,200 and the center of the button would be their?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use null layouts
2. Don't use setPreferredSize(...)

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers

For example:

```
JButton button = new JButton( "Tailand" );

JPanel left = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
left.setBackground( Color.WHITE );
left.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Flag Menu");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frane.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.add(left, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
frame.setSize(600, 400);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and example of using each layout manager.

Comment: Thank you for this. now i want to put the other buttons with it. Do i have to create another panel and put the button there or is their a better way to put all the buttons in one panel and put it at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Nuggethed2003,  `Do i have to create another panel`  - why don't you try it? How long would it take to try it? That is how you learn. In any case the answer is, yes, Then all the components you add to the panel will be at the bottom. That is the essence of using layout managers, You can nest panels with different layout managers to achieve the desired layout.